# Not able to get SVN for Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am trying to install svn plugin for eclipse, through help-->Install New Softwares tab, when I type http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x in the work with tab and press on Add button, I do not see any options as shown in http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-enable-subversion-svn-in-eclipse-ide/ link.. Any idea on whats wrong?

I am running Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choose Help|Install New Software.

At Dialogue Click on Add

You should get the "Add Site" Dialogue.

In Name, type Subclipse.
For Location: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Then Click "Ok".

Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am using but I do not see install box with any components

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing it from Ubuntu's package manager (the "Software Centre").
You can generally be sure software packaged with the OS is all the same version, and dependancies are generally handler for you.